# Issues writing to S3 using s3-streamlogger

Tags: amazon-s3, winston, aws-sdk-nodejs, multi-factor-authentication

I'm writing in NodeJS and trying to send winston log data to S3 bucket using s3-streamlogger, but I get **access denied**.

Testing it from the CLI it is working fine read and write. the only reason I can think of is that we are using MFA in our AWS account.

Any ideas? workarounds?
Thanks

Comment: I'm facing the same problem! We're using MFA as well and I'm receiving "AccessDenied" error code.